# How to calculate a common encryption key between sender and receiver

Tags: symmetric, key-exchange

In the picture below, for the text underlined in red color: 7X(MOD 11) = 72(MOD 11) =49(MOD 11)

My questions are:

(1) obviously there is no equal relationship between 72(MOD 11) and 49 (MOD 11), and where does 49 come from?

(2) X and Y are picked up randomly, are 7 and 7 in 7X and 11 in MOD 11 also picked up randomly, or is it some algorithm？ there is no any explanation in the textbook I have

(3) in the text marked in blue color, where does 2401 come from?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1) obviously there is no equal relationship between 72(MOD 11) and 49 (MOD 11), and where does 49 come from?

It's not $72$, it's $7^2 = 7 \cdot 7 = 49$.

> (2) X and Y are picked up randomly, are 7 and 7 in 7X and 11 in MOD 11 also picked up randomly, or is it some algorithm？ there is no any explanation in the textbook I have.

No, they are not random. This is simply [the Diffie-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). 7 is the base (or generator) and 11 is the modulus. These are pre-established configuration parameters.

Of course, to be secure, they need to be a whole lot larger - about 2048 bits or higher for the modulus.

> (3) in the text marked in blue color, where does 2401 come from?

Similar, this is bad printing, it's just $7^4$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in answering mode - should have left this for a newcomer.

Comment: it is very clear and thanks

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you use WolframAlpha and enter 2401 you get [this page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2401) with the nice remark: "$2401 = 7^4$ is a perfect $4^{th}$ power."